# Facing error 'firebase.auth() is not a function' web app

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am learning Firebase. And make a simple login form and I want user Authentication at login when user submit its id and password.but I am getting error in my console.

> Uncaught TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function at login

Can anyone Know about that? Help

HTML code

```
 <div id="login_div" class="main-div">
    <h3>Firebase Web login Example</h3>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email..." id="email_field" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." id="password_field" />

    <button onclick="login()">Login to Account</button>
  </div>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDZ7YPz6jpAW4J966W5pB9voy6u4abTNMw",
    authDomain: "example-196de.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://example-196de.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "example-196de",
    storageBucket: "example-196de.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "22033570312",
    appId: "1:22033570312:web:88f5683b2bb8c2692dcfbd",
    measurementId: "G-DVMKC50VBB"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();



  </script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
```

Js code

```
function login(){

  var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  var userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);

    // ...
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following cdn:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

To use Firebase Auth

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#from-the-cdn

Comment: Got it.But why firebase not give this by default as giving other script?

Comment: because not all apps will use firebase auth, some wont use it thats why. They add the cdn so you can copy and use whichever u need

Comment: Thank bro.. for help